# Laravel Echo with Pusher and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I use Laravel as a server part and Vue Cli as a client.
Also I use https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/
But I have a errors in console log when i try connect vue client to laravel websockets.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://http//websockets.test:6001/app/myKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.1.1&flash=false' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

WebSocket connection to 'wss://http//websockets.test:443/app/myKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.1.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sockjs-mt1.pusher.com/pusher/app/myKey/659/6nenb2dd/xhr_streaming?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.1.1&t=1583092642805&n=1' from origin 'http://app.vuesocks.test:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my code in Vue Cli index.js Echo options

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'myKey',
  cluster: 'mt1',
  authEndpoint: 'http://websockets.test/broadcasting/auth',
  wsHost: 'http://websockets.test',
  wsPort: 6001,
  disableStats: true,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer myToken...',
    },
  },
});
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']);
```

channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function () {
    return 'Hello!';
});
```

if remove `wsHost` and `wsPort` then there are no errors, but nothing happens, there is no response from the server.

Comment: Are you running **php artisan websockets:serve**? In most cases when connection is closed before receiving a response is due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has probably already been solved but to anyone who is still having trouble getting their frontend to listen for events, what worked for me was reverting pusher-js back to version 5.1.1, found the answer on this issue on the repo: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/365

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Laravel and Vuejs), it was working in localhost but when I host to a vps CORS issue was showing in the console.
I changed pushers-js version from 6.0.0 to 5.1.1, that worked for me.